# If an integral over the plane vanishes, prove that it vanishes on a square.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-measure

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure $m\times m$  on $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Prove that if $$\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x,y)dxdy=0$$ then there exists a square 
$S_{a,b}=\{(x,y)\,|\, a\le x\le a+1,\; b\le y\le b+1\}$,
such that
$$ \iint_{S_{a,b}}f(x,y)dxdy=0$$

My try:  The union of all squares $S_{a+i,b+j}$ ,$i,j \in \mathbb{Z}$, covers the whole $\mathbb{R^2}$. Fix some enumeration of the set $ \{ S_{a+i,b+j} \}_{i,j} $ and denote it by $ \{ S^{a,b}_{n} \}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ . We can epress $\mathbb{R}^2$ as the disjoint union $$ \mathbb{R^2}=\bigsqcup^{\infty}_{n =1} S^{a,b}_{n}$$ Therefore $$\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x,y)dxdy=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \iint_{S^{a,b}_{n}}f(x,y)dxdy=0$$ because the series converges, $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \iint_{S^{a,b}_{n}}f(x,y)dxdy =0 $ for any enumeration. But I can not find a rigorous way to show that over one of the squares the integral vanishes, because we can not consider a particular pattern in which positive and negative integrals cancel out each other. Should I fix an enumeration in which the $1\times 1$ squares are adjacent ?

Hints\suggestions are more appreciated than answers. Thank you in advance.

Comment: An idea to consider: Set $g(a,b)=\displaystyle\int_{S_{a,b}} f(x,y)dxdy$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks ! Let me see if I got it right .... g(a,b) is (hopefully) a continuous function, on a compact subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{R^2}$ it has to take positive and negative values, by intermediate value theorem , there exists some point $(a^*,b^*)$ in $\Omega$ for which $g(a^*,b^*)=0$... Did I get it right ?

Comment: You don't need compactness. But you do need to argue continuity and why there must be positive and negative values;)

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks Again :) To prove continuity, I argued like this: Given $\epsilon > 0$, I need to find $\delta > 0$ such that if $(s,t)$ is a point inside a $\delta-$ball around $(a,b)$, then $|g(s,t)-g(a,b)|<\epsilon$.   $$|g(s,t)-g(a,b)|=|\iint_{\Omega}f(x,y)dxdy| \leq \iint_{\Omega}|f(x,y)|dxdy $$ where $\Omega$ is the L-shaped region we get as the set-theoric difference $S_{s,t} \setminus S_{a,b}$. My issue is If I knew that $f(x,y)$ is bounded over $\Omega$, say $|f(x,y)|<M$, for some large $M$, then $|g(s,t)-g(a,b)| \leq M m\times m (\Omega) < \epsilon $, which proves the continuity

Comment: But I don't know if $f(x,y)$ is bounded over $\Omega$ or not...
By the way, for proving the fact that $g$ must take positive and negative values in a neighborhood of some point $(a,b)$, I can prove by contradiction: If ,say, $g>0$ for all points, then the integral over the plane can not be equal to zero.

Comment: Right: You're not out of the woods yet. You don't know $f$ is bounded, but you do know it's $L^1$.

Comment: In my dreams : It would be great if I could say something like $\iint_{\Omega} |f(x,y)| dxdy = m\times m (\Omega) ||f||_1$ In fact I can say : $\iint_{\Omega} |f(x,y)| dxdy = \iint_{\mathbb{R^2}} |f(x,y)||\chi_{\Omega}(x,y)| dxdy \leq ||f||_1||\chi_{\Omega}||_{\infty}=||f||_1$ By Holder ($\chi_{\Omega}$ is the characteristic function of the set $\Omega$)... But it does not help... Can you please tell me how can I use the fact that $f$ is integrable ?

Comment: It's the typical game. On a compact set $K$, what do you know about $K_n=\{x\in K: f(x)\ge n\}$?

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't know .... But I know this : $$\int_{K_n} f \geq n. m(K_n)$$ well, $\Omega$ is a compact set. So it can be said that the measure of the set of points in $\Omega$ where $f(x,y)\geq M$ has a small measure (if $M >> 0$) ? Am I right? how does that help me? Sorry that I ask you a lot of elementary questions :-|

Comment: So you're asking questions about Lebesgue integration/measure theory. I assume you've learned some of the standard results? :) It's very hard to guess what you know and what you don't, but this should be relatively straightforward.